# Don't we need DeprecatedConstructorForDeserialization() In Corda State while deleting a state field for 4.9 Enterprise version?

Tags: kotlin, migration, deserialization, blockchain, corda

I was trying to test some deletion scenarios of fields in a Corda state. But I was wondered that it doesn't throw deserialisation  error while retrieving the older data, even without providing deserialisation constructors for the deleted field.

And yes, I confirm that older version state has data in it for this particular field.

Is it handled somehow in 4.9 Enterprise version?

Edit: The datatype of my deleted field were **String?** & **String** (tested both). Will test customDataType soon, is it like String Corda will manage? (though, dont we need a matching class constructor for deserialising the old state data blob?)

This https://corda.net/blog/a-developers-primer-on-cordapp-upgrades/ blog also suggest to provide deserialisationConstructor!

Answer (score 1):

This can be a situation when you delete nullable fields, when a state after removing nullable fields is detected by the Corda serialization framework, properties that don’t have matching parameters in the main constructor are simply omitted from object construction.

To read more take a look here https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.7/enterprise/serialization-default-evolution.html

Comment: Thanks for the response @sneha. 
May I know, how about the non-nullable fields? while constructing the object from olderstate blob using latest constructor (the one with field removed), will that existing data also be ignored?