# What is the difference in deserialization of state vault data in corda node while retrieving using vault query versus using in a transaction?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, migration, blockchain, corda

I was trying to understand the Corda behaviour, while removing a state field and did migration without cleaning vault data.

Interestingly, I found that removed field is completely ignored while doing a vault query in test cases for both nullable & non-nullable without even having a **deprecatedconstructorfordeserialization**()

But when I tried using the old state vault data for a transaction in newer cordapp version, it thrown me this error.

> [ERROR] 2023-03-21T07:17:25,242Z [flow-worker] transactions.TransactionBuilder. - The transaction currently built will not validate because of an unknown error most likely caused by a
> missing dependency in the transaction attachments.
> Please contact the developer of the CorDapp for further instructions. {fiber-id=10000002, flow-id=e0065196-739b-4265-b369-d9168929ea82, invocation_id=9150889e-4fcc-4851-9085-ce6d8699cafc, invocation_timestamp=2023-03-21T07:17:24.613Z, origin=O=ABC Node One, L=London, C=GB, session_id=9150889e-4fcc-4851-9085-ce6d8699cafc, session_timestamp=2023-03-21T07:17:24.613Z, thread-id=195}
>
> java.io.NotSerializableException:
> net.corda.core.contracts.TransactionState (erased) ->
> data(net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState) ->
> com.abc.fgh.corda.contracts.states.cars.CarState -> Non-null
> value ff7678ff-dd67-49b6-be7d-933a487c0a7b provided for property
> dltNonNullField, which is not supported in this version

With deserialisation constructor addition, these got resolved.

Q1) What is the difference in **deserialization of old data blob data** while doing a **vault query** versus in using a **corda transaction input state**?

Q2) Why it still got this **serialization** error for **nullable field** as well?

[Don't we need DeprecatedConstructorForDeserialization() In Corda State while deleting a state field for 4.9 Enterprise version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75744981/dont-we-need-deprecatedconstructorfordeserialization-in-corda-state-while-del)
&
https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.7/enterprise/serialization-default-evolution.html#removing-properties
It is said that nullable field can be easily removed without constructor!

Please shed some light into these. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Ben, can you confirm which corda version you were using before and which is the newer version which you are using ?

Comment: Hi @sneha, it is 4.9 Enterprise Corda

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to deprecate the field instead of removing. Removing non-nullable properties is impossible. If a node receives a message containing a serialized form of an object that has fewer properties than it requires for construction, it can’t determine sensible defaults.

It is technically possible to remove nullable properties in some circumstances as Alex talks [here](https://medium.com/corda/a-developers-primer-on-cordapp-upgrades-3806c2e7f81e).

Apart from this, I will need to look at the your test case to determine why its not working with the test case.

Comment: Hi @sneha, but I am able to remove the non-nullable field and able to use that state in a new transaction after migration by adding a deserialisationConstructor. (the deserialisationConstructor args has this old field and returning args simply ignore this field) Isn't sound correct for you?